# Keycloak Certificate Authentication

Tags: ssl, keycloak

I want a authentication flow for certificate authentication in keycloak and followed this [docs from keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_x509).

i generated the keystore and truststore with these commands

```
keytool.exe -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias localhost -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password123 -validity 360
keytool.exe -export -alias localhost -file localhost.cer -keystore keystore.jks
keytool.exe -import -v -trustcacerts -alias localhost -file localhost.cer -keystore truststore.jks
```

and also made the changes in xml file, now in the [troubleshooting part](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#troubleshooting-2) I'm not getting how to generate *client_cert.crt* and *client_cert.key*. also it is mentioned they need to be in .pem format.

Can somebody help how i move forward with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want mutual SSL between users and keycloak?, I've tried to do the same thing, but it didnt work, i've tried every thing on keycloak doc, but users were never prompted to choose a cert, eventually i used wildfly official documentation, and it finnaly worked!

src: https://docs.wildfly.org/18/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#configure-ssltls

Comment: Yeah I've gone through the link and found it useful. Next I want an application like https://dzone.com/articles/securing-rest-apis-with-client-certificates but with using keycloak. Any idea how do I do that ?

Comment: In wildfly doc, follow "4.3.2. Enable Two-way SSL/TLS in WildFly for Applications", and you will get the same config as in your example. the user trying to reach an api, will be redirected to keycloak, which will ask for the client cert, and perform the mutuall ssl handshake.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided I suggest you to double-check if all instructions were followed.

Have you configured a X509 Browser flow?

This flow should be selected for authentication through KC> Authentication> Bindings

The source identity is also an important part to map the certificate to an user, so check if this is properly configured as well.

On my side I tried a mapping by Serial Number, and it works.

I had to create an user attribute called **usercertificate** with a value of 0D (my certificate Serial Number) in Keycloak > Users > [testuser] > Attributes.
The certificate was imported in my browser, and during authentication phase my browser popups the browser certificate for selection.